# devise forgot password and html5 modal window

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html, devise

I want to, if a user click by devise the link "forgot password" it should appear a modal window and then after put email in the input field and send, it should redirect to login page.

it should be html5 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) it supports modals.